# XML Service incorrectly and unpredictably parsing DateTime field

Tags: .net, web-services, xml-serialization

I have an Entity with the following property:

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return new DateTime(this.Ticks); }
    set { this.Ticks = value.Ticks; }
}
```

It sets the field Ticks, which is how the DateTime is stored in the database.

The problem is, I see XML come in with a Date field formatted like this:

```
<Date>2011-04-08T12:29:00.000Z</Date>
```

Which is a perfectly fine string representation of a DateTime.  And in testing, this string parses to the DateTime you would expect it to.

But the date in the system gets set to 2011-04-10 12:29, or exactly two days into the future.

This happens inconsistenly, and unpredictably.  I can makes hundreds of submissions, and all of them are correct.  But when the client submits them in the wee hours of the morning, a handful of them end up with dates two days into the future.  This leads me to several, currently unanswerable, questions:

1. What constructor or parsing method is used when the XML is deserialized into a DateTime?
2. The client is in Central time, our server is on Eastern time,(even though all times are always converted to GMT) does this have any impact?
3. What clues does the fact that most of the errors occur in the early morning hours, but cannot be reproduced the rest of the day, give me, or is this just a strange coincidence?

**UPDATE:**

After reading the following blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/07/387677.aspx It appears that .net DateTime does indeed have issues with deserialization.  And it does indeed use the local server time, even when it shouldn't.  This doesn't explain ALL my issues, but it does lead me to the decision to stop using the DateTime type in XML services, and instead have the client submit datetimes as ticks instead.  As long as .Net doesn't fail at parsing longs, we should be ok.

**UPDATE 2:**

The client was against submitting datetimes as Ticks, as each OS has a different definition of what Ticks are, (client is on Java, not sure what OS)  So we decided to use strings.  The client did not change their submitted XML at all, but we would be able to manually parse the string to a datetime instead of letting the deserializer do it.

I have updated the Property like so:

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public string Date
{
    get { return new DateTime(this.Ticks).ToString(); }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            this.Ticks = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                this.Ticks = DateTime.Parse(value).ToUniversalTime().Ticks;
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem still exists, at 1AM this morning the client imported approximately 20 records, and only 2 of them had the date mysteriously moved forward.  After looking at the raw XML of both the successfully parsed date and those that weren't, I see no difference in the format at all.

Any help at tis point greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the time is different on some machines. I don't buy "two days".

Comment: 2011-04-10 12:29 is not two days after 2011-08-25T12:29:00.000Z

Comment: @John Saunders:  there have been cases where the time is off by an hour or two, but those were all attributed to the assumption of one time zone over another, or not factoring in DST.  But the case in which the date gets parsed 2 days into the future is real, and should not be impacted by the current datetime of the server at all.

Comment: @phoong: i mistyped, fixing it now

Comment: @Neil: I just can't see how a timezone issue could result in a 48-hour difference. Human error is a better explanation of that.

Comment: @John Saunders:  We have logged the submitted XML on both ends, and it is always correct.

Comment: And like I said in the OP, the time zone issue may not be a factor at all.

Comment: @Neil: pardon me for saying "time zone". "Time delta" would be a better term, and, again, I suspect human error. Neither server is on the other side of the International Date Line, is it?

Comment: @John Saunders: no, both servers are in the USA, the submitting server is CST, the receiving server is EST, but again, why would it matter?, the string is passed as GMT, it only gets converted to the local time when viewed on a webpage, in which case it converts it to whatever time zone the users account is set to.  But I have verified the actual ticks that get saved to the DB are indeed two days into the future.

Comment: @Neil: I read your edit and the link, and I don't think that's the problem you're having. The problem described in that post is that times are being converted to local time, instead of UTC time. Also,  you are always receiving times with the "Z" at the end, so the serializer should be converting GMT (Z) time to local in all cases. This conversion should only produce different results to the extent that the local timezone is different. Also, a conversion to local can only affect time zone - which can only produce a 24 hour delta.

Comment: @Neil: I think you need to look elsewhere for the source of your problem. I would look at the conversion to ticks, at any manipulation of ticks, and at whether some code is maybe converting to "next business day" or something like that. Can you log the DateTime and ticks being received by the service, at the very start of the service operation?

Comment: @Neil: also, is WCF an option? You might not need to deal with the XML Serializer at all.

Comment: @John: I agree, this doesn't make sense and I have a team pulling their hair out for weeks now.  But if it did make sense, I wouldn't be asking for answers here.

Comment: @Neil: Any new developments on your issue? Did you check my answer below? I hope you found the cause!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely a weird case. A couple of things can alter the result of the parse.

1. CultureInfo: by default Parse uses CurrentCulture. If you have something funny on your globalization settings that triggers the change of your current culture, that could be affected.
2. Per MSDN: 'The Parse method attempts to parse a string with several implicit parse patterns' and if you throw culture patterns in it, you can end up with quite a mess.

My suggestions to try:

1. Use the ParseExact method instead of Parse and enforce a format on your date time string.
2. Use InvariantCulture when parsing your date time (if your application date time format is universal, which I assume it is since you are storing ticks)

On your setter try this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))  
{  
   this.Ticks = 0;  
}  
else  
{  
   CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;  
   var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", provider);  
   this.Ticks = dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;  
}
```

Good luck!

**Edit 1**
Something else came to my mind: ThreadSafety. If you are accessing the reflected object of Ticks (in your setter you do this.Ticks) from multiple threads you should make it an atomic operation.

```
//same setter code except last line...
var oldTicks = this.Ticks;
var newTicks = dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;  
while(oldTicks != Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.Ticks, newTicks))  
{ //your break code here  }
```

Sorta :)
Let me know if any of this helped to solve the mystery.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen issues such as this, but did encounter problems where timezone information is lost from a .NET 2.0 SOAP webservice when the WebService method returns a `DateTime` rather than an object which *contains* `DateTime`.

From that experience I learned that you should quickly focus on ensuring you can isolate and reproduce the problem.  I would suggest you build a test-harness.

Using a sample DateTime value which you know has failed in your full system, emulate a client sending infinite requests.  Run the service test-harness in Debug mode with a breakpoint to pause execution the moment it receives a value different from what was inspected.  Using a tool such as Fiddler to also capture the Client traffic can provide additional insight.

If that fails to turn up the issue, then you should re-evaluate the evidence you have and again repeat the process as the next candidate is identified.  Don't be afraid to retry something you believe you've tested or looked through before, the devil is nearly always in the details with these.

---

One other thought -- is it possible that this could be a concurrency/multithreading issue?  If you have hard evidence that a particular value was submitted and a different value was received, then have you looked to ensure the received value was sent by a different client--or could be set from a different location within the system?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix these issues by stating that all transported dates (moved between remote systems) are in fact [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), for example:

```
public DateTime StartDateUtc
{
...
}

public DateTime EndDateUtc
{
...
}
```

And you leave the responsability of conversion to and from local time only to user interfaces code (or the highest layers of your application).

Note you can't really enforce this *technically*, only by convention / documentation, and making sure properties and methods are semantically marked "as UTC". A bad programmer will always be able to pass a local date to these properties:

```
StartDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow; // this is correct
StartDateUtc = DateTime.Now; // this is wrong
```